# User root can't write to file in /tmp owned by someone else in 20.04, but can in 18.04

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, 20.04, root

In Ubuntu 18.04, I can create a file as one user in `/tmp`, and write to it as user `root` (despite the sticky bit being set on `/tmp`).

In Ubuntu 20.04, I get a `Permission Denied` error as user `root`.

**Ubuntu 18.04:**

```
# As user "ubuntu":
touch /tmp/tmplock

# As user "root":
echo "foo" > /tmp/tmplock

cat /tmp/tmplock
# Outputs "foo"

ls -lah /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 32 root   root    20K Jun 16 18:36 .
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    4 Jun 16 18:36 tmplock
```

**Ubuntu 20.04:**

```
# As user "ubuntu":
touch /tmp/tmplock

# As user "root":
echo "foo" > /tmp/tmplock
# Outputs: bash: /tmp/tmplock: Permission denied

ls -lah /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 12 root   root   4.0K Jun 16 18:15 .
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Jun 16 18:14 tmplock
```

I can't find any information on if this is related to the sticky bit, or an underlying Linux kernel change, or anything.

Does anyone know what can explain the change in behavior?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To change the behavior back to the 18.04 default:

```
sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0
```

See the accepted answer to

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503111/group-permissions-for-root-not-working-in-tmp

Sigh, sometimes the cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Beyond running that command on every login, is there a way to make the setting permanent?  Seems it goes back to 2 every time I reboot.

Comment: @IpsRich See the other answer for a permanent change to this new system default.  It's a security issue, so you should understand the consequences of the change.

Comment: Thanks @ubfan1 - don't know how I missed that!  I've decided to try to avoid `/tmp` where I can instead, and use the `TMPDIR` environment variable to tell things like `tmpfile` to use e.g. `~/tmp` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The root user should always be able to edit any and all files.  The only correct response is to disable the `sysctl fs.protected_regular` setting until it gets fixed (i.e. so that root can edit anything on the system).

The [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251030/618353) has a temporary solution that doesn't stick between reboots.

If you want to make the `fs.protected_regular=0` change permanent between reboots, edit the `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/protect-links.conf` file.

Make the above change, then save and reboot to verify that it is working as expected.

Comment: What makes you think that this is something that needs to be fixed?

Comment: @Seir What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: @ForrestVoight This: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5