# Permission denied to a 777 file

Tags: permissions, log, django

I have a `Django` app which is configured to write db queries into a `/tmp/db.log` file.

```
        "debug_console_to_file": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "filters": ["require_debug_true"],
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "/tmp/db.log",
        },
```

The application usually starts from a `uwsgi` server using `www-data` as a user.
However, sometimes I manually run it (with `python manage.py`) via my user - `tvelichkov`.

The problem is that when I try to start it from my user, I got a Permission denied error to `/tmp/db.log` file since `www-data` has already created it (removing the file can temporary fix the issue, but then the server will receive the same error, since now my user owns the file).

```
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/db.log'
```

I've tried to add my user to `www-data` group

```
    $ members www-data
    www-data tvelichkov
```

I've also tried to give `777` file permissions to the file.

```
    $ ls -l /tmp/db.log 
    -rwxrwsrwx 1 www-data www-data 22102 юли 30 15:25 /tmp/db.log
```

But I still keep getting this `Permission denied` error. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I used to have no issues with this setup in Ubuntu 18.04, but now I have it in Ubuntu 20.04.

UPDATE: Here are the permissions of the `/tmp/` folder, but note that this is after I ran `chown root:root /tmp` and `chmod 777 /tmp` as suggested by @adrian vera, BTW after this change seems like `chmod 777 /tmp/db.log` is working, because I no more get the Permission denied error. Is it possible that Ubuntu changed something for the `/tmp/` folder between versions 18.04 and 20.04 ? Because I'm pretty sure I didn't change anything to this folder before running into this issue?

```
    $ ls -l / | grep tmp
    drwxrwxrwx  24 root root       4096 авг  3 10:19 tmp
```

Note2: I have one more machine with clean Ubuntu 20.04 install where I have this issue too, I will double check the permissions there too once I got home.

UPDATE2: So on a clean Ubuntu 20.04 install the permissions of the `/tmp/` folder are:

```
    $ ls -l / | grep tmp
    drwxrwxrwt  23 root root      12288 авг  3 16:41 tmp
```

And this is how the `/tmp/db.log` look like:

```
    $ ls -l /tmp/db.log 
    -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 авг  3 16:54 /tmp/db.log

    $ sudo chmod 777 /tmp/db.log 
    $ ls -l /tmp/db.log 
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 0 авг  3 16:54 /tmp/db.log

    $ lsattr /tmp/db.log 
    --------------e----- /tmp/db.log

    $ whoami
    tvelichkov

    $ getent group www-data
    www-data:x:33:tvelichkov

    $ python manage.py test --settings=cs.settings.test
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/tvelichkov/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 565, in configure
        handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
      File "/home/tvelichkov/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 738, in configure_handler
        result = factory(**kwargs)
      File "/home/tvelichkov/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1032, in __init__
        StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
      File "/home/tvelichkov/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1061, in _open
        return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/db.log'
```

Comment: Do ***not*** set `/tmp` to 777. It should be left at 4777. Otherwise you have created a ***huge*** security hole. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71622/what-are-correct-permissions-for-tmp-i-unintentionally-set-it-all-public-recu) for details.

Comment: Can you please add output of `lsattr /tmp/db.log`

Comment: @DigvijayS yes, its: `--------------e-----`, I've also updated it in the question.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250974/user-root-cant-write-to-file-in-tmp-owned-by-someone-else-in-20-04-but-can-in/1251030#1251030 To restore the 18.04 behavior, run sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0

Comment: Holy sh**, @ubfan1 yep I can confirm this setting is causing the issue, no more errors with `fs.protected_regular=0`. However, reading about this settings, I feel like its more appropriate to go with @pa4080 approach, it looks like a more general fix, which better fits to the bounty description (Otherwise I would have asked you to post this comment as an answer so I can give you the bounty). Anyway I just wonna finish this with a BIG THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, instead of deal with the permissions, in this case, it is a better idea to execute the script as the `www-data` user. This is standard approach which we use to run the maintenance scripts of some web apps like NextClud, MediaWiki, etc. You can do that by the help of the `sudo` command:

```
sudo -u www-data python manage.py
```

Comment: I agree that this is probably the best approach not dealing with permissions. I just wonna give some more fight to the permission issue, since its something that used to work, and I wonna learn why it stopped. BTW, using your code as-is throws `sudo: python: command not found`, I guess full path to python is required and since we use virtual envs: `sudo -u www-data /home/tvelichkov/.pyenv/shims/python manage.py` works OK.

Comment: @Todor, yes your python apparently doesn't belong to the default `$PATH` and you need to use the full path to the executable. I appreciate your curios to look deep as possible into the problem. Just keep in mind if you deal with the permissions of directories like `/tmp` they will fall back to the defaults after each reboot, so you will need to execute additional script...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have set particular user id as  group ownership of file.
(See s in **rwxrwsrwx** file permissions details.)
That's why you are getting permission denied with tvelichkov username.
You need to turn off user id and set group id in file ownership.

```
sudo chown g-s www-data: /tmp/db.log
```

I would suggest that you should use same user to run and test application.
That would avoid these kind of issues.

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly the command, because it throws `chmod: cannot access 'www-data': No such file or directory`. Btw after restart the default file permissions are: `-rw-r--r--`. And seems like I may have changed something to the /tmp/ folder, because following @adrian vera answer, after running `chown root:root /tmp` and `chmod 777 /tmp`, only now running `chmod 777 /tmp/db.log` generates `-rwxrwxrwx` (i.e. no s) and indeed there is no error anymore! Did I correctly restored the /tmp/ folder and can i somehow change the default file permissions to be different than `-rw-r--r--`?

Comment: ```/tmp``` folder typically have the permission ```rwxrwxrwt```. The last ```t``` is required so that a user can not delete files created by other users. To set this bit use ```sudo chmod o+t /tmp```. Since you have added yourself to ```www-data``` group you can have permission ```664``` on the ```db.log``` file.

Comment: @turbulence, now after I added `t ` as you suggested the `tmp` forlder permissions are `drwxrwxrwt`, I've also changed the `db.log` perms to `777` and now they are: `-rwxrwxrwx` and started getting the error back. I'm not sure how exactly `logging.FileHandler` works internally, (if he tries to delete the file before using it, could this be reason for the error? But i've just tested the exactly same setup (permission wise) on one of my colleges machine with Ubuntu 18.04 and it WORKS. Everything is the same, except I'm running 20.04 and got the error.

Comment: Make sure that you have sudo access or you can switch to root to change ownership.

Comment: @todor Can you show what command exactly you tried ans throw error ?

Comment: @KKPatel it was exact copy/paste of your command: `sudo chmod g-s www-data /tmp/db.log`. But I'm not sure if this `s` permission is still relevant, because I don't have it anymore (check comments + the UPDATE-s in the question). For now it looks like the error is caused by the `t` flag in the `/tmp/` folder, the strange this is that this flag still persists in Ubuntu 18.04 and there is no such error `o_O`.

Comment: I have edited answer. Kindly re-check and try. Let me know if any get any error.

Comment: Thanks @KKPatel, but as i've already mention, the problem turns out not to be the `s` flag in the `db.log` file (I don't have it anymore), but the `t` flag in the `/tmp` folder. And this is only when this `t` flag is combined with Ubuntu 20.04 new default `fs.protected_regular=2` (Props to @ubfan1 for pointing this out). There is no error when `sysctl fs.protected_regular=0` (Like in Ubuntu 18.04).