# Can't edit file in /tmp with 777 permissions even when root; Can delete;

Tags: permissions

I have a file that's owned by `www-data:www-data` and has `rwxrwxrwx` permissions. Despite being root I can't write to it, however I can remove it. The `/tmp` folder has `drwxrwxrwt` permissions.

Where the problem might be?

```
# Can't write to file
root@app-web:/data/app# >> /tmp/app.log
bash: /tmp/app.log: Permission denied

# Permissions on file
root@app-web:/data/app# ls -alt /tmp/app.log 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 18788 /tmp/app.log

# I can remove it
root@app-web:/data/app# rm -r /tmp/app.log

# Create it 
root@app-web:/data/app# touch /tmp/app.log 

# Write to it
root@app-web:/data/app# >> /tmp/app.log 

# Once I change owner back to www-data
root@app-web:/tmp# chown www-data:www-data /tmp/app.log

# I can no longer write
root@app-web:/tmp# >> /tmp/app.log
bash: /tmp/app.log: Permission denied
```

```
root@app-web:/data/app# lsattr /tmp/app.log
--------------e--- /tmp/app.log
```

```
root@app-web:/data/app# getfacl /tmp/app.log
# file: app.log
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

My `/tmp` folder sits in `/` mount.

```
overlay on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/JYPNMY5ACNKQ4ZF6Z43DCI2ITB...upperdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf343e129700f4357a4d24bd0a9782d094e8e51f21e06932111ec432a3ab27dc/diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf343e129700f4357a4d24bd0a9782d094e8e51f21e06932111ec432a3ab27dc/work,xino=off)
```

Permissions of /tmp
`drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 tmp`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the file because you have write permission for the *directory* that it's in.

Most likely the file has an ACL (*Access Control List*). Use `getfacl` (from the *acl* package) to see it.

There is also the `setfacl` command to set those ACLs.

Comment: I've added results from `getfacl`. It doesn't seem that permissions are any different than the ones returned by `ls`. Thanks for explaining the reason I can delete the file. It's helpful.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250974/user-root-cant-write-to-file-in-tmp-owned-by-someone-else-in-20-04-but-can-in/1251030#1251030 to change this behavior.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, that's it. I now understand the issue, I don't think that ultimately the answer is: `sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0`. I don't think I want to change the default secure behaviour, I'll simply stay away from: `/tmp` in my case and I will try to do it elsewhere in a controlled environment. It has two benefits, I don't affect the `/tmp` default security settings. I am not likely to be affected in the future if rules change for `/tmp` again. At least that's best conclusion I got so far.

Comment: `man chattr` suggests the `e` refers to [filesystem extents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extent_(file_systems)) rather than [extended file attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes)

Comment: @steeldriver: You are right. Removed from the answer.