# python script always give file not found even when file exists ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python

On ubuntu 18.04 everything was working fine but when we upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 our python script:

```
import os
os.path.exists('/tmp/file.csv')
```

above code gives `False` even though the file exists.

I google it and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250974/user-root-cant-write-to-file-in-tmp-owned-by-someone-else-in-20-04-but-can-in) by setting `fs.protected_regular` to 0 but that did nothing. However when I switch to root the script seems to be working. And on the server even the root user returns False.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the correct command. `os.path.exists` checks for a PATH. Not a file. `Use os.path.isfile`

- `os.path.exists()` – Returns True if path or directory does exists.
- `os.path.isfile()` – Returns True if path is File.
- `os.path.isdir()` – Returns True if path is Directory.
- `pathlib.Path.exists()` – Returns True if path or directory does exists. (In Python 3.4 and above versions)

Comment: If that were the case then why does it work when I switch to root user ? I think you have not understood my question