# permission denied when executing "exec" on /tmp Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, scripts, 22.04, execute-command

I have the script below, it works fine for Ubuntu 18.04

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
# This form is convenient for locking a file without spawning a
# subprocess. The shell opens the lock file for reading and
# writing as file descriptor 9, then flock is used to lock the
# descriptor.
# Source: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html
ansible_path="/tmp/ansible-pull.lck"
touch -a $ansible_path
chown ubuntu:ubuntu $ansible_path
exec 9<>$ansible_path
flock -n 9
```

when I executed the script on Ubuntu 22.04 , I got error

```
sudo ./deploy.sh
./deploy.sh: line 11: /tmp/ansible-pull.lck: Permission denied
```

The error line is: `exec 9<>$ansible_path`. I think this is the problem with /tmp folder, as changed `ansible_path` to `/var/ansible-pull.lck` make it work. But I don't know what wrong with /tmp which is not mount to any file system

```
mount |grep tmp
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=475076k,nr_inodes=118769,mode=755,inode64)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=192760k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=192760k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=96376k,nr_inodes=24094,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
```

something might be different on /tmp directory between 18.04 and 22.04?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User root can't write to file in /tmp owned by someone else in 20.04, but can in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250974/user-root-cant-write-to-file-in-tmp-owned-by-someone-else-in-20-04-but-can-in)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `/tmp` directory has the sticky bit on it. That means, only the owners of files in that directory can modify them.

Since you are changing the owner to `ubuntu`, then whoever is trying to edit that file will get a permission denied error, even the `root` user.

You have several options in your case.

1. Remove the `chown ubuntu:ubuntu $ansible_path` line.
2. Remove the sticky bit from `/tmp` (Not recommended!).
3. Create a directory in `/tmp` and create the files in that directory

ref: [Permission denied in /tmp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687711/3574)

Comment: The sticky bit also enabled by default in Ubuntu 18.04, but did not got this issue

Comment: see 1250974 for the sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0  fix