# User not able to modify the file which is created by a different user. User is also part of that user's group

Tags: permissions, filesystem, users

I have created two normal users on my Ubuntu system:

**testuser1
testuser2**

I have added **testuser2** to the **testuser1** group

testuser1 created a file in the `/tmp` folder named **file1**, **testuser2** is able to read the file1 but not edit it. What could be the possible reason?

The root user is also able to read **file1** but not edit it.

I have run the command `ls -l /tmp/file1`

and get the output : `-rw-rw-r-- 1 testuser1 testuser1 6 Aug 29 22:19 /tmp/file1`

That means the group have the **read** and **write** permissions still enduser2 is not able to edit **file1**

I also run the command `umask` for both of user and got `002`.

Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User root can't write to file in /tmp owned by someone else in 20.04, but can in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250974/user-root-cant-write-to-file-in-tmp-owned-by-someone-else-in-20-04-but-can-in)  A default security feature since 18.04.